# Process substitution removes new-line and replace with space?

Tags: bash, sh

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a org
while IFS=$'\n' read -r line
do

    org[0]+=$line+"\n"
done < <(iptables -L INPUT -v -n )

echo "${org[@]}"
```

Output i get is

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes) pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         47668 9923K RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Where in-fact it should be

[image: iptables output]

**update with set -x**

```
+ echo -e 'Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes) pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         48315 9974K RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           '
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes) pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         48315 9974K RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you declare org as an array but use only first element in the loop while trying to output all elements (`[@]`) when the loop is over. Second "\n" in bash is a string made of 2 chars '\' and 'n'. It has no special meaning. as @Thomas stated, echo -e will interpret `\n` as newline.

To add to an array see question [SO 1951506](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951506/add-a-new-element-to-an-array-without-specifying-the-index-in-bash).

Your apparent goal is to simply read and echo all lines from an input. Use cat. Or better, just the plain output of your `iptables -L INPUT -v -n` command. It will output what you want.

@Thomas' answer produces the correct output. But you can also go this way if you like things more complicated than simply running the command that already produces the correct output :

```
declare -a org
while IFS=$'\n' read line
do
    org+=( "$line" )
done < <( iptables -L INPUT -v -n )
printf '%s\n'  "${org[@]}"
```

or this, if you want to embed the \n in each array element.

```
declare -a org
nl=$'\n'
while IFS=$nl read line
do
    org+=( "$line$nl" )
done < <( iptables -L INPUT -v -n )
echo  "${org[@]}"
```

Comment: +1 thanks, I didn't wanted the output of iptables to be saved in each index element but only single i.e org[0] shall contain whole output for this i change to `org[0]+` and its working fine now! thxs

Comment: ... if you want the lines of a file in a bash array there's no need for an explicit loop: you can use `mapfile` (or its synonym `readarray`) ex. `mapfile -t org < <(iptables -L INPUT -v -n)`

Comment: thank you @steeldriver for mentionning `mapfile`. I did not suspect it existed.

Comment: @asadz, to capture the whole output in a variable, you can use `$( cmd )` which is much simpler than the loop. `org[0]=$(iptables -L INPUT -v -n)`. Only the final "\n" is removed. add it again if you need it. `org[0]=$(iptables -L INPUT -v -n)$'\n'`.

Answer (score 1):

`echo` does not interpret backslashes escapes by default and `\n` is not recognized as newline therefore. You can enable the interpretation with `echo -e`.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a org
while IFS=$'\n' read -r line
do

    org[0]+=$line+"\n"
done < <(iptables -L INPUT -v -n )

echo -e "${org[@]}"
```

Comment: Can you add `set -x` just before the `echo` command and add the output to your question.